# Solution of $x-1=(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)(x-\{x\})$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find all solutions for $$x-1=(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)(x-\{x\})$$

$$$$My approach:
$$x-1=\lfloor x \rfloor\{x\}$$

$$\dfrac{x-1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}=\{x\}$$
$$\Rightarrow 0\le \dfrac{x-1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}<1$$

$$Case 1: 0\le \dfrac{x-1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$$
This gives me the solution set $(-\infty,0)\cup[1,\infty)$$$$$
$$Case 2:\dfrac{x-1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}<1$$
$$\Rightarrow\dfrac{x-1-\lfloor x \rfloor}{\lfloor x \rfloor}<0$$
$$\dfrac{\{x\}-1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}<0$$
Since $0\le\{x\}<1\Rightarrow \{x\}-1<0 $. Thus to make the above condition true, $\lfloor x \rfloor$ must be positive. Thus, $x\ge 1$

Taking the intersection of the solution sets for both cases, $x\in[1,\infty)$$$$$
However this answer is clearly wrong; the given answer is $x\in[1,2)$

Could somebody please tell me where $I've$ made a mistake? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simplifies to $\lfloor x \rfloor \{x\} =\lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\} - 1$, or $(\lfloor x \rfloor - 1)(\{x\}-1) = 0$.

Since we cannot have $\{x\}=1$, we have $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$, which gives all solutions.

Comment: Thank you Sir, but actually I was hoping that I'd get to know where I went wrong with my method. Could you please tell me where my solution is wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: @user342209 You've proved that, as long as $x$ is at least $1$, then $\frac{x-1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ lies in $[0,1)$.  But it doesn't just have to lie in that interval, it actually has to equal $\{x\}$.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Sir, from my method, where the last thing I've done is show that as long as $x$ is at least $1$, $\dfrac{ x-1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$$ \in [0,1)$. From here, how could I find the value for which it is equal to $\{x\}$?

Comment: @user342209 I don't know if this is possible.  Somehow, you have to eliminate the case $x>2$, but I'm not sure whether there should be a way to do this that is simpler than solving the problem from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lfloor x \rfloor=n,\{x\}=\epsilon$, then $x=n+\epsilon$.
The equation (1)
$$x-1=(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)(x-\{x\})\tag{1}$$

becomes

$$n+\epsilon-1=\epsilon n\tag{2}$$
or

$$n(1-\epsilon)=(1-\epsilon)\tag{3}$$

Since $0\le\epsilon<1$, we have $1-\epsilon>0$, thus from (3) we can solve for $n$ and result is $n=1$.

Consequently $x=1+\epsilon$ where $0\le\epsilon<1$.

Comment: Thank you Sir, but actually I was hoping that I'd get to know where I went wrong with my method. Could you please tell me where my solution is wrong? Thanks!